# Clearing TextBox After Button Click React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app in which I have a TextBox and a button. When I click on the button I want the TextBox value to be cleared. How can I achieve this without using a form?

```
 const [name, setName] = useState('') 

 const handleChange = e => {
   setName(e.target.value)
 }

 const handleSubmit = () => {
  // clear the TextBox
}
 

 <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
 <button onClick={handleSubmit}></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in cases like this, `input` values are stored in state, which in your case it is called `name`

So you need to also map the input value to the state, then just set the value of `name` to nothing:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('') 

 const handleChange = (e) => {
   setName(e.target.value)
 }

 const handleSubmit = () => {
  setName('')
}
 
<input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
<button onClick={handleSubmit}></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [name, setName] = useState('') 

 const handleChange = (e) => {
   setName(e.target.value)
 }

 const handleSubmit = () => {
  setName('') // clear the TextBox
}
 

 <input type="text" value={name} onChange = {handleChange}  />
 <button onClick = {handleSubmit}></button>
```

Comment: bcz your input was not controlled. i updated my ans. you have to pass your state as `value` of the input to make it controlled input

Comment: I added the value attribute on input type text and set the value to be the name and then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: React recommends to use controlled input. see details here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components.